# Read vector<char> as stream

Tags: c++, stl

I have a CONST vector lying around, but need a function to read from it. The problem is, the function expects an istream.

What's the most efficient way to pass the data inside the vector to this function?

I tried this approach to prevent copying the stream, but it doesn't work because my vector is const and pubsetbuf expects a non-const char *.

```
istringstream is;
const vector<char>& data = GETDATA();
is.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(&data[0], data.size());
```

As the stream is read-only, I could cast the pointer. Is that safe?
Or any better ways?

Comment: @luk32 No it's for work :(

Answer (score 6):

Consider using [Boost.Iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html):

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

using namespace boost::iostreams;
stream<array_source> bs(data.data(), data.size());
std::istream &is = bs;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write you own stream:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ostream>

// BasicSequenceInputBuffer
// ============================================================================

template < typename Char, typename Traits = std::char_traits<Char> >
class BasicSequenceInputBuffer
:   public std::basic_streambuf<Char, Traits>
{
    // Types
    // =====

    private:
    typedef std::basic_streambuf<Char, Traits> Base;

    public:
    typedef typename Base::char_type char_type;
    typedef typename Base::int_type int_type;
    typedef typename Base::pos_type pos_type;
    typedef typename Base::off_type off_type;
    typedef typename Base::traits_type traits_type;
    typedef const char_type* pointer;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;

    // Construction
    // ============

    public:
    BasicSequenceInputBuffer(pointer data, size_type size) {
        // These casts are safe (no modification will take place):
        char* begin = const_cast<char_type*>(data);
        char* end = const_cast<char_type*>(data + size);
        this->setg(begin, begin, end);
    }

    // Stream Buffer Interface
    // =======================

    protected:
    virtual std::streamsize showmanyc();
    virtual std::streamsize xsgetn(char_type*, std::streamsize);
    virtual int_type pbackfail(int_type);

    // Utilities
    // =========

    protected:
    int_type eof() { return traits_type::eof(); }
    bool is_eof(int_type ch) { return ch == eof(); }
};


// Get Area
// ========

template <typename Char, typename Traits>
std::streamsize
BasicSequenceInputBuffer<Char, Traits>::showmanyc() {
    return this->egptr() - this->gptr();
}

template <typename Char, typename Traits>
std::streamsize
BasicSequenceInputBuffer<Char, Traits>::xsgetn(char_type* p, std::streamsize n) {
    std::streamsize result = std::min(n, this->egptr() - this->gptr());
    std::copy(this->gptr(), this->gptr() + result, p);
    this->gbump(result);
    return result;
}

template <typename Char, typename Traits>
typename BasicSequenceInputBuffer<Char, Traits>::int_type
BasicSequenceInputBuffer<Char, Traits>::pbackfail(int_type ch) {
    if(is_eof(ch)) {
        if(this->eback() != this->gptr()) {
            this->gbump(-1);
            return traits_type::to_int_type(*this->gptr());
        }
    }
    return eof();
}

typedef BasicSequenceInputBuffer<char> SequenceInputBuffer;


// BasicSequenceInputStream
//=============================================================================

template < typename Char, typename Traits = std::char_traits<Char> >
class BasicSequenceInputStream
:   public std::basic_istream<Char, Traits>
{
    private:
    typedef std::basic_istream<Char, Traits> Base;

    public:
    typedef typename Base::char_type char_type;
    typedef typename Base::int_type int_type;
    typedef typename Base::pos_type pos_type;
    typedef typename Base::off_type off_type;
    typedef typename Base::traits_type traits_type;

    private:
    typedef BasicSequenceInputBuffer<Char, Traits> buffer_type;

    public:
    typedef typename buffer_type::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename buffer_type::size_type size_type;

    // Construction
    // ============

    public:
    explicit BasicSequenceInputStream(pointer data, size_type size)
    :   Base(&m_buf), m_buf(data, size)
    {}

    private:
    buffer_type m_buf;
};

typedef BasicSequenceInputStream<char> SequenceInputStream;


// Test
// ====

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "Hello World";
    const std::vector<char> vector(s.begin(), s.end());
    SequenceInputStream stream(vector.data(), vector.size());

    std::string line;
    std::getline(stream, line);
    std::cout << line << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put into your answer. But I think I will just copy the vector.

Comment: @NeilKirk Note: there is no copy done here (the start and end of the sequence are stored in the existing stream pointers). But if memory (size) is no issue, a plain copy is reasonable and good enough.